# Chrome Dev Tools - Hiding errors from specific files

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've just updated to Chrome 35 and now I no longer have the option to filter out errors or console messages from specific files.

Normally I would just right click the message and select "Filter" -> "Hide messages from ..." but I no longer have that option - Only option in the menu is "Unhide all" which is disabled.

[image: Filter]

Does anyone know why?